# script/server returns development database not configured? Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to run server I get:

=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establis
h_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotS
pecified)

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3
```

.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55
:in `establish_connection'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
```

initializer.rb:437:in `initialize_database'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
```

initializer.rb:141:in `process'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
```

initializer.rb:113:in `send'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
```

initializer.rb:113:in `run'

```
    from C:/Sites/lbtco/config/environment.rb:13
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_
```

require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_
```

require.rb:29:in `require'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.
```

3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.
```

3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.
```

3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
```

commands/server.rb:84

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_
```

require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_
```

require.rb:29:in `require'

from script/server:3

C:\Sites\lbtco>

Answer (score 1):

It says it right in the first textblock, `your development database is not configured`

Run

```
rake db:migrate
```

in your console. Maybe you have to edit `config/database.yml` first.